# How to sort the list?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

how to sort below customers list by its MemberRole such as Golden first then Silver, and the rest are order by their Firstname & Lastname.

```
public class  Customer
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; } 
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string memberRole { get; set; } // Golden and Silver 
}

List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
customers.OrderBy(c => 
   c.memberRole == "Golden" ? 0 : (c.memberRole == "Silver" ? 1 : 2))
 .ThenBy(c => c.FirstName)
 .ThenBy(c => c.LastName)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OrderByDescending` with a bool where `true` is *higher* than `false`:

```
customers  = customers 
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.memberRole == "Golden")
    .ThenBy(c => c.Firstname)
    .ThenBy(c => c.LastName)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Ha. How do you know there is no "Bronze" role?

Comment: @Blaise: because of his comment: _"// Golden and Silver"_

Answer (score 1):

From the point of design, it will be better to put member roles comparison into separate class. This way you can easily reuse it, unit-test and upgrade in case if new roles will appear. For LINQ compatibility, better to implement IComparer class.

```
public class MemberRoleComparison : IComparer<string>
{
    // Put in required order from most importan to less
    internal static readonly string[] ROLES = { "Golden", "Silver", "Bronze" };

    int IComparer<string>.Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return Array.IndexOf(ROLES, x).CompareTo(Array.IndexOf(ROLES, y));
    }
}
```

Then sorting will look like:

```
var sorted = customers
    .OrderBy(item => item.memberRole, new MemberRoleComparison())
    .ThenBy(c => c.Firstname)
    .ThenBy(c => c.Lastname)
;
```

If it is possible by specification, you might want to replace string representation of the role with enum.

```
public enum MemberRole
{
    Golden = 1,
    Silver = 2,
    Bronze = 3
}
```

Then you can compare roles directly like a "customer1.memberRole > customer2.memberRole".

If you want to optimized speed and memory consumption (usually 30-40% faster), its better to use List.Sort routine. At first define customer comparison reusable class:

```
public class CustomerComparison : IComparer<Customer>
{
    private IComparer<string> _RoleComparer = new MemberRoleComparison();

    int IComparer<Customer>.Compare(Customer x, Customer y)
    {
        int result = _RoleComparer.Compare(x.memberRole, y.memberRole);
        result = result == 0 ? string.Compare(x.Firstname, y.Firstname) : result;
        return result == 0 ? string.Compare(x.Lastname, y.Lastname) : result;
    }
}
```

And then just use Sort method of existing list:

```
customers.Sort(new CustomerComparison());
```

But for even better performance you might want to use parallelized LINQ:

```
var sorted = customers
    .AsParallel()
    .OrderBy(item => item.memberRole, new MemberRoleComparison())
    .ThenBy(c => c.Firstname)
    .ThenBy(c => c.Lastname)
;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var result = customers
    .Select(z => new
        {
            OrderableRole = role == "Golden"
                ? 1
                : role == "Silver"
                    ? 2
                    : int.MaxValue,
            Customer = z
        })
    .OrderBy(z => z.OrderableRole)
    .ThenBy(z => z.Customer.Firstname)
    .ThenBy(z => z.Customer.LastName)
    .ToList();
```